# Как в unity привязать значению элемента ссылку на переменную

Tags: c#, unity3d

В приложении надо сделать возможность выбора цвета элементов, но в приложении довольно таки много кнопок и менять каждой из них цвет перебором будет очень не оптимизированно. Так вот, каким образом можно это реализовать по другому, нету варианта задать всем кнопкам в параметре ссылку на переменную, которая будет определять цвет?

Comment: Со стороны C# это сделать нереально. `Color` - это struct, т.е. value type, внутри элементов юнити хранит копии этой структуры. Но, вообще говоря, элементы то рендерятся не C#, а шейдерами, вам ничего не мешает рендерить какие-то кнопки 1 материалом с установленным цветом, смена цвета на материале сменит цвета всех кнопок.

Comment: Если не материал, то через `event system`. Написать скрипты для каждого типа элементов реакцию на некое событие ~`uiColorChange` и всё.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker думаю, ваш вариант сработает, оформите в виде ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждой группы элементов, разделяющих один цвет, можно сделать общий материал, изменение цвета которого изменит цвет всех элементов.

Answer (score -1):

Размышления на тему того как бы попробовал бы я сам:

1. Создать класс-враппер на цвет:

```
public class MyColor{
    public var colorVal = Color();
}
```

2. Создать собственный класс кнопки унаследованный от базовой кнопки. Имеющий доп.пропертю типа MyColor
3. в `Start()` При помощи UnsafeCode используя pointer присвоить значение из MyColor.color в цвет кнопки
4. отслеживать изменения в классе кнопки и в MyColor. Где было изменение - оттуда и обновлять данные в другом месте.

должно сработать. Но не факт :)

---

Или же, как сказал RiotBr3aker - применить на все нужные кнопки материал и изменять значение цвета в нем.

Comment: `отслеживать изменения в классе`? long polling? серьёзно? Паттерн `Observer` для кого придумали?

Comment: @Yaroslav я НИЧЕГО не говорил об реализации отслеживания. Все додумал ты себе сам. Или обсервер уже не отслеживает изменения?)